# How to translate "dirty" in the morally unclean sense?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

I'm looking for a good translation of the word *dirty*, in the sense of

> Morally unclean; obscene or indecent, especially sexually. ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dirty#Adjective))

E.g:

> _*_* Gedanken
>
> Ein *_*_ Witz
>
> _*_* reden

Which word could I use?

Comment: Can dirty in English be applied to persons? E.g. **dirty woman** or is that just the title of a movie? I would hesitate to translate it with neither **schmutzig** nor **versaut** in this context.

Comment: @benrd_k: a "dirty woman" could be a woman who is slutty, dishonourable, hot or covered with dirt.

Comment: Lol, +1 for "covered with dirt"

Comment: unanständig oder anstößig come to mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The proper translation would be *schmutzig*:

> Er erzählte einen schmutzigen Witz

The word *dreckig* is less often used in this sense, but will be understood as well.

Comment: *Dreckig* is just much stronger than *schmutzig*, both in the original and in the figurative sense.

Comment: But _dreckig_ has slightly different semantics, it is more like _nasty_ in my opinion.

Answer (score 8):

"Obszön" would be a good choice when speaking or writing in a more formal context.

Answer (score 7):

Another related alternative would be “**versaut**”, literally “spoiled”, and with much the same connotation.

The difference between the German “versaut” and English “spoiled” – and the reason why it can also be used in the sense of “dirty” – is this: A “spoiled joke” is a joke badly told. But a “versauter Witz” (usually) means a dirty joke.

(Likewise, you can’t say “das ist eine versaute Frucht” to warn somebody off eating a spoiled apple.)

Comment: Can you talk about "versaute Gedanken denken" and "versaut reden"?

Comment: Also, would a phallus-shaped pear be a "versaute Frucht"?

Comment: @Tim “versaute Gedanken” – definitely! Same for “reden”, though this would be used much less frequently. And yes, the phallus-shaped pear (or Shakespeare’s [poperin pear](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=poperin%20pear)) is *the* example of a versaute Frucht.

Answer (score 5):

> *Schlüpfrige* Gedanken.
>
> Ein *schlüpfriger* Witz.
>
> *Schlüpfrig* reden.

Comment: Is this local? [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=schl%C3%BCpfrig) doesn't seem to list such meanings.

Comment: @Tim I don't know. I've only heard it being used and used it myself in the meaning of "[sexually] dirty". [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=schl%C3%BCpfrig) lists a couple of English translations matching that meaning (afaics). It's a pretty informal term though. "schlüpfrig " auto-completes to "schlüpfrige witze" / "schlüpfrige gedichte" (among others) on google.

Answer (score 1):

*Unflätig* may also make sense as a translation:

> Unflätige Worte, Gedanken

For some uses (e.g. joke), it's used less often today though.

Comment: To me, *unflätig* has a meaning that's closer to "rude" than to "sexually suggestive" - though obviously, the latter will be the former to some people. *Unflätig* is also more disapproving than *schmutzig* or *dreckig*, which can, like "dirty", be used without passing judgment, or even approvingly.

Comment: @fzwo: True. Yet it may be an appropriate translation for dirty. Some dictionaries also list it (e.g. dict.cc). Look at the definition in the question, *morally unclean* is very subjective. It can also be used humorously - then it may actually also express approvement.